# iMac Display Replacment

Tags: imac, display

I have a 2007 iMac 24inch, and I’m starting to notice the display is giving out (very opaque lines across a section of the screen, which sometimes do not appear.  It is the display though, as I confirmed this at the Apple store), and my warranty has expired (162 days past). The cost of a replacement is $500+, which would be insured up to two years if Apple replaced it.  I just don’t see the benefit, as the monitor is just starting to show this, and I’m not really sure how much more time I will get from the current display.

Does anybody have any good experienced with third-party vendors? Or, a good place to purchase a new display? I live in San Francisco.  I’m looking for a cheaper display, otherwise, I might just wait until this one dies completely, then hook another monitor up to it, and mirror the display.  I would rather buy a Mac Pro vs dishing out 500+ into my current iMac.  Any suggestions, ideas?

Note: This is not the glass in front of the display, it’s the display itself.

**Edit:** I had to make a small edit. My warranty has expired 162 past the orginal date, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm going to answer this in general since there is good information about that specific model even while avoiding the off topic area of asking questions for a specific recommendation of a vendor. With a little general knowledge, you'll quickly find local shops that do repairs but I'll not call anyone out.

Answer (score 1):

I would go back to the Apple store to speak with a technician again. Apple repair service has historically been warranted for 90 days or the remainder of the existing coverage (one year or three from original purchase if you have AppleCare) so if you are outside the first year the numbers don't add up. It should be written on the back of the quote they provided you. They might even give you some options for [other local service providers](http://www.apple.com/buy/locator/service/) that have passed the hardware repair tests to work on Macs but you can always look them up yourself.

The internal LCD panels for that model are integrated with a frame, and a driver board so you're not just buying a commodity 24" LCD panel. You are also buying expertise in case it's not the LCD panel but a video card or the cable. I don't know of many shops that can beat Apple's current labor rates of $39 so you would hope to get a good feeling about why the shop can beat apple's price so much on parts. I always feel better when a shop can explain to me why the parts they use are cheaper than the manufacturer's parts so I can make a good decision.

It's not as hard a repair as say the graphics card or the logic board in that model, but you'll find lower labor rates and better parts prices from shops that do a high volume of that model repair.

Once you've got some quotes you can make a better call in your situation - it might make sense to buy an external monitor even if it's more costly that the repair - especially if that investment will carry forward to an eventual new mac.